# select particular columns and automatically create new table in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table with columns as follows :

```
no  | fname | lname | address | contact | startd | expiryd |category
```

I wanted to create  new tables automatically without modifying the original one

new Table1

```
  no |  fname | category
```

new Table2

```
no | fname  | lname |   address
```

new Table3

```
fname | contact |   startd |    expiryd
```

Is there any way to do so ?

Comment: "need answer urgently" - please note this is a community site where people choose questions to answer based on personal priority and quality of the question. If you really need urgent help better to hire a professional.

Comment: have you tried pivot tables? (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) Or you can just duplicate your sheet and delete not necessary columns, seems to be quick and straightforward.

Comment: Do you really have a `table` in excel or is it just the way that your data is laid out. Many a times people think they have [tables](http://www.contextures.com/xlExcelTable01.html) - in reality they don't

Comment: yup I have ,i need to know how to automatically recreate child tables

Comment: +1 on using pivot tables. It's the cleanest, fastest and most flexible way to do it.